# Linearity requirement for a time to voltage converter in a two-step TDC

Tags: adc

I am working on a project where I need to design a 6-bit two-step time to digital converter. The two step scheme consists of a time to voltage converter followed by an ADC. The TVC converts the time into voltage, and this voltage is used by ADC to convert to digital representation.

The ADC works with a reference voltage of 1V, so one LSB resolution of the ADC is 1/64=15.6mV/LSB. The full scale input dynamic range of the TDC is 1ns, which corresponds to a 15.6ps resolution for the TDC as a whole. If we assume there is a one-to-one correspondence between LSBs of the TDC and ADC, then for 15.6ps of the change in time there corresponds a 15.6mV change in each step of the ADC transfer function. This is all I know.

Now what about the linearity requirement for the intermediate element TVC? How much accurate does it have to be if I want to guarantee the one-to-one map between LSBs? And also how can I measure TVC linearity so that I make sure it fits well within 6b precision of the ADC?

Comment: If you want to *measure* the linearity, you'll need to have an independent method for measuring the time that's at least as accurate as the system you're trying to build.

Comment: I am using a circuit simulator to test the circuit behavior at simulation level first. So  generating time for TVC is not a big deal. However, I can use an accurate DTC to generate time as an independent method.

Comment: If you're in a simulator, it should be easy to model the effects of TVC nonlinearity (of various forms) on the performance of the overall system. You can then develop your component requirements from that knowledge.